# Where are exec() method's variables defined?

Tags: python, variables, exec

I was trying to run a little code that convert a string to a list, when I felt on this problem.
First of all here is an example code :

```
def str_to_list(s):
    s = s.replace('\n', '')
    exec('res="{}"'.format(str(s)))
    print(res)

s = '[0. 1. 0. 0.\n 0. 2. 5.]'
l = str_to_list(s)
```

When I run this, I get a NameError about `res`, at first I thought that it can be a sort of local variables into the exec() method, but then i realised that i could run this code:

```
s = '[0. 1. 0. 0.\n 0. 2. 5.]'
s = s.replace('\n', '')
exec('res="{}"'.format(str(s)))
print(res)
```

Since the fact that I'm not trying to call `res` from outside the function, and the fact that I can run this code alone, I can't figure out where is the problem.

I try some searches on the internet, but due to my lack of knowledge in low-level execution, I can't find keywords that define my specific problem.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you think you need `exec` for this task? FWIW, your 2nd code block sets `res` to the string `'[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 2. 5.]'`; it doesn't create a list.

Comment: @PM2Ring It was just for the example, I simplified the code to be sure that the error is not caused by something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [the `exec` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) you need to give `exec` an appropriate `locals` dictionary. Eg,

```
def str_to_list(s):
    s = s.replace('\n', '')
    d = {}
    exec('res="{}"'.format(s), None, d)
    return d['res']

s = '[0. 1. 0. 0.\n 0. 2. 5.]'
print(str_to_list(s))
```

*output*

```
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 2. 5.]
```

However, it is generally advised that you avoid using `exec`, unless you *really* need it. For details, please see Ned Batchelder's [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). The info there also applies to `exec`.

---

If you simply want to create a list from a string, you can probably use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). Eg,

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = '[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5]'
seq = literal_eval(s)
print(seq, type(seq))
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5] <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CPython, local variables in a function are (usually?) stored in a fixed-size array, in an optimization known as "fast locals". As a result, local variables cannot be dynamically added to a function.

The exec function will attempt to add the new local variable to the function, but it will not be read by the return statement because that fixed-size array did not change.